# <router-view/> Rendering the same component within itself

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In my main `App` component I have the template setup like this:

```
 <div v-if="authenticated" id="app">
    <template v-if="user && metadata">
      <registration v-if="user.user_type.match(/patient/i) && !metadata.registration_complete"/>
      <template v-else>
      ...
      </template>
    </template>
 </div>
```

and the `Registration` component's template looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="patient-registration">
    <div class="container">
      <router-view/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I want the `Registration` component to render it's children routes, so I have the routes set up this way:

```
{
  path: '/registration',
  // name: 'Registration',
  component: Registration,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      name: 'Agreements',
      component: Agreements
    }, {
      path: 'information',
      name: 'PersonalInfo',
      component: PersonalInfo
    }
  ]
},
```

But the output html renders Registration within itself before rendering it's child `Agreement` like this:

```
<div data-v-6062c645="" class="patient-registration">
    <div data-v-6062c645="" class="container">
        <div data-v-6062c645="" class="patient-registration">
            <div data-v-6062c645="" class="container">
                <div data-v-0bd02235="" data-v-6062c645="" class="agreements">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using this type of pattern else where and it's working as expected. I am not sure why in this case `Registration` component is being rendered within itself once before rendering it's children. How would I get it to render like this?

```
<div data-v-6062c645="" class="patient-registration">
    <div data-v-6062c645="" class="container">
        <div data-v-0bd02235="" data-v-6062c645="" class="agreements">
           ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have the "root" Registration component hardcoded in the App template, then in *that* you have a `<router-view/>` which will render the Registration component in its place when the `/registration` path is matched. That's the cause of the Registration component being rendered inside itself.

Comment: Okay I see, I replaced that with another `<router-view/>` and got the desired effect, although I think I need change up how I am structuring my components now. Thanks!